# vector field on tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

I am studying geodesic flows on manifolds and I have problem visualizing it. How should one think about geodesic vector field on tangent bundle? How can you visualize it? Any intuition is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: I like to think a geodesic flow as motion that follows the "path of least resistance", the natural motion that an object would follow in "real life" if, say, you roll a ball along some surface. But perhaps specialists have a better way of imagining it.